# How to set caption of TMS AdvSmoothLabel with proper alignment in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi

Below is a screenshot of a TMS AdvSmoothLabel with alignment set to Bottom Right.

As can be seen in the pic, there is a small amount of space always left between the RHS of Label and RHS of Label's caption. What i wanted was something like the TLabel:-

[image]

I tried going through TMS units and i was only confused.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : Sorry for the delay. I should ask TMS .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you have yet asked TMS Software or if you have been replied to but the way to do what you require is to turn Wordwrap ON

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would have though it would be the margins, but testing them I can't get them to do anything.

I have two work arounds to suggest.:

1. Set the Caption Location to plCustom and then set the Caption's Top and Left settings. This might be annoying for you if your form is resizeable and you want to keep the text to the left.
2. Hide the bit of the background you don't want under a panel, or off the form or something.